# Replacing comma in a csv file

Tags: php, regex, csv

I have an CSV File with the following content:

```
"Title","Firstname","Lastname","Description"
"Mr","Peter","Tester",,
"Mrs",,"Master","Chief, Supporter"
"Mr","Seg, Jr.","Tuti","Head, Developer"
```

Now I want to remove the quote sourrounded comma by `preg_replace` (`"Chief, Supporter"`; `"Seg, Jr."`; `"Head, Developer"`).

But I am not able to build a suitable Regex.

My last result looks like: `/\"(.[^\",]*),(.[^\"]*)\"/i`

Comment: Could you show how your desired output looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are a little unclear, but if I understand correctly, you want to remove the comma if one exists within a double-quoted string so that

e.g. `"Head, Developer"` becomes `"Head Developer"`, etc

Based on that assumption then

```
/\"([^\"]+?),+ *(\w[^\"]+?)\"/gmi
```

will find those commas, and

```
"$1 $2"
```

will replace it with a space.

see [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/aP3oS7/3)

PHP example (I'm not very conversant with php so the character escaping, etc might need tweaking)

```
<?php
$string = '"Mr","Seg Jr.","Tuti","Head Developer"';
$pattern = '/\"([^\"]+?),+ *(\w[^\"]+?)\"/gmi';
$replacement = '"$1 $2"';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this regex: `((?>\*\*)),((?>\*\*))`

Capture the `**` in parentheses and replace with `,`, see [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/uN5sU3/1)